# Why does the float object behave differently with the "is" operator?

Tags: python, immutability, cpython, python-internals

As far as I know cpython implementation keeps the same object for some same values in order to save memory. For example when I create 2 strings with the value `hello`, cpython does not create 2 different `PyObject`:

```py
>>> s1 = 'hello'
>>> s2 = 'hello'
>>> s1 is s2
True
```

I heard about it with name *string interning*. When I tried to check it with other python types I observed that almost all hashable (immutable) types are the same:

```py
>>> int() is int()
True
>>> str() is str()
True
>>> frozenset() is frozenset()
True
>>> bool() is bool()
True
```

And almost all mutable types are the opposite (cpython creates a new `PyObject` even for the same values):

```py
>>> list() is list()
False
>>> set() is set()
False
>>> dict() is dict()
False
```

And I think it's because we can have the same `PyObject` for immutable objects without having any problem.

My question arises when I see that the `float` type behave differently than other immutable types:

```py
>>> float() is float()
False
```

Why is it different?

Comment: *"almost all mutable types are the opposite"* -- Why do you say "almost"? All mutable types behave like that, no?

Comment: @wjandrea just because I wasn't sure.

Comment: `float(0.0) is float(0.0)` but `float(0) is not float(0)`, and `help(float)` says the signature is `float(x=0, /)`, so I bet under the hood, `float()` gets turned into something like `float(0)`. I tried looking at [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/31ff96712e8f89ac1056c2da880b44650002219f/Objects/floatobject.c) but I don't know enough C to make sense of it.

Comment: The decision on how any given object type handles interning is rather arbitrary, and differs by type.  For ints, it's all values in the range -5 thru 256 (this has changed over the years), on the grounds that such values are quite commonly used.  For strings, it's values that look like Python identifiers.  For floats, there's no particular pattern to what values are likely to be reused, so no interning is done at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mutable objects always create a new object, otherwise the data would be shared. There's not much to explain here, as if you append an item to an empty list, you don't want all of the empty lists to have that item.

Immutable objects behave in a completely different manner:

- Strings get *interned*. If they are smaller than 20 alphanumeric characters, and are static (consts in the code, function names, etc), they get cached and are accessed from a special mapping reserved for these. It is to save memory but more importantly used to have a faster comparison. Python uses a lot of dictionary access operations under the hood which require string comparison. Being able to compare 2 strings like attribute or function names by comparing their memory address instead of the actual value, is a significant runtime improvement.
- Booleans simply [return the same object](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/396b58345f81d4c8c5a52546d2288e666a1b9b8b/Objects/boolobject.c#L28). Considering there are only 2 available, it makes no sense creating them again and again.
- Small integers (from -5 to 256) by default, [are also cached](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/396b58345f81d4c8c5a52546d2288e666a1b9b8b/Objects/boolobject.c#L28). These are used quite often, just about everywhere. Every time an integer is in that range, CPython simply returns the same object.

Floats however are not cached. Unlike integers, where the numbers 0-10 are extremely common, `1.0` isn't guaranteed to be more used than `2.0` or `0.1`. That's why `float()` simply returns a new float. We could have optimized the empty `float()`, and we can check for speed benefits but it might not have made such a difference.

The confusion starts to arise when `float(0.0) is float(0.0)`. Python has numerous optimizations built in:

- First of all, consts are saved in each function's code object. `0.0 is 0.0` simply refers to the same object. It is a compile-time optimization.
- Second of all, `float(0.0)` takes the `0.0` object, and since it's a float (which is immutable), it [simply returns it](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/31ff96712e8f89ac1056c2da880b44650002219f/Objects/abstract.c#L1635). No need to create a new object if it's already a float.
- Lastly, `1.0 + 1.0 is 2.0` will also work. The reason is that `1.0 + 1.0` is calculated on compile time and then references the same `2.0` object:

  ```
  def test():
      return 1.0 + 1.0 is 2.0

  dis.dis(test)
    2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (2.0)
                2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2.0)
                4 IS_OP                    0
                6 RETURN_VALUE
  ```

  As you can see, there is no addition operation. The function was compiled with the result pointing to the exact same constant object.

So while there is no float-specific optimization, 3 different generic optimizations are into play. The sum of them is what ultimately decides if it'll be the same object or not.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! First, I noticed that the link regarding small integer objects is mistakenly the same as the link regarding Boolean objects. Second, I noticed that `id` often (but not always) returns the same identity for floating point objects that are calculated at compile time, regardless of value. However, when I call `id` on multiple such floating point objects in a single expression (e.g. `(id(0.1), id(0.2))`), the identity changes for all but one. So comparing identities unexpectedly behaves as expected (i.e. `(id(0.1) == id(0.2)) is False` . What's the deal with that?

Comment: @TylerCrompton I'll fix the link, sorry about that. Where did you see the same id on different floats at compile time?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/kx5Es0jz

Comment: Oh. I think that I understand why. The documentation for `id` says that the identities are guaranteed to be unique among simultaneously existing objects. It says nothing about uniqueness otherwise. Additionally, it goes on to say that CPython uses the object's memory address. I suppose that CPython simply reuses that memory for literals whenever possible.

Comment: @TylerCrompton your assumption is 100% accurate :-)